# How to safely increment database using django rest framework?

Tags: sql, django, transactions, django-rest-framework, increment

I'm facing some troubles by trying to make a like/unlike system for my app.

It's okay when i like/unlike in a normal timelapse, but when i click multiple times in a very short frequency (20 clicks in 10 seconds for example) then my counter is disturbed.

Normally while i'm testing my counter should always have a value of 1 or 0 since i am the only one to do the operation. However when i click quickly and multiple times, my rest api cannot follow the rythm and i'm getting a counter that have 7 or 8 likes.

I've tried multiple solutions. first by adding the model transaction included with django. As a decorator :

`@transaction.atomic`

Or manually :

```
     with transaction.atomic():
     #do stuff
```

I've also tried to increment directly from the database by using `F()` :

`votes=F("votes") + 1`

Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: don't allow more than one vote. No?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Vote Up/Down method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528583/django-vote-up-down-method)

Comment: how do you check if user already voted?

Comment: votes=F("votes") + 1 does exactly what you need. The problem probably exists somewhere else.

Comment: @kevswanberg Probably. i think when i test it my backend doesn't have the time to process before another request come. So it create a disturbing. No i need to find a way to freeze de request until the `HTTP 200 OK` come to my client.